# How can I skip rails warden authentication for sidekiq engine route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq, sidekiq-monitor

I am using sidekiq 4.1.4 with Rails 4.2.6.

The route file has below code:

```
require 'sidekiq/web'
mount Sidekiq::Web, at: '/sidekiq'
```

When I access sidekiq UI through http://localhost:3000/sidekiq, it shows error:

```
{
    "errors": [
        "Unauthorized Request"
    ]
}
```

I'm using warden authentication and the initializer file has this code:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_after ActionDispatch::ParamsParser, Warden::Manager do |manager|
  manager.default_strategies :authentication_token
  manager.failure_app = UnauthenticatedController
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to access sidekiq at http://my_domain.com/sidekiq with these changes:

Create an initializer with below code:

```
class MountedAppAuth
  def initialize( app )
    @app = app
  end

  def call( env )
    @app.call( env )
  end
end
```

In routes.rb:

```
require 'sidekiq/web'
Sidekiq::Web.use MountedAppAuth
mount Sidekiq::Web, at: '/sidekiq'
```